# How to change tags after the DOM is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to change a `span` tag to an `img` tag in the run time.

This is my html block:

```
<body onload="mediaInputFilter ()">
<section data-role="page" data-theme="ams">
    <section data-role="header" >
        <h1>header ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss</h1>

    </section>
    <section data-role="conents" id="mycontent" >
        <p>loruim epsum haha&nbsp;</p>\n<p>hehe told u&nbsp;</p>\n<ol class="starpasspro-upper-alpha_ol">\n<li>gasdfg</li>\n<li>sdfffasd</li>\n<li>asdfffasdf</li>\n<li>asdfasdfasdfasd</li>\n</ol>\n\n<table class="table_with_header lsm-tableclass-styles">\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class="lsm_table_heading_1">Description</td>\n<td class="lsm_table_heading_1">Amount</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Gross salary</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: income tax (£35,000 x 25%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: social security tax (£50,000 x 9%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Net earnings</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Employer’s contribution on social security<br>(£50,000 x10.5%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n\n
        <p><span data-lscp-resource-mimetype="image/png" data-lscp-resource-id="00001"></span></p>


    </section>
    <section data-role="footer">
        <p>footer</p>

    </section>
</section>
```

After the html is executed all the span tags need to be converted in to `img` tag automatically.

I tried this with the other way round it did work but in this scenario it is not working.

Here is my js (this is written in jQuery)

```
 function mediaInputFilter(){
        $($("section[data-role='conents']").html()).find("span[data-rcb-resource-mimetype^=image]").each(function (i,node) {

        var imgNode = $(node);
        var src = '../images/00001.png';
        var spanNode = $("<span/>");

        spanNode.attr("data-rcb-resource-mimetype", imgNode.attr("data-rcb-resource-mimetype"));
        spanNode.attr("data-rcb-resource-id", imgNode.attr("data-rcb-resource-id"));
        spanNode.attr("src", src);

        imgNode.after(spanNode);
        imgNode.remove();
    });
}
```

Any help with this please tell me where I am wrong or if you have another solution I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

Your changes are not persisting because you are making changes to a node that is destroyed as soon as this code runs.

See http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

Solution:

Replace

```
$($("section[data-role='conents']").html()).find("span[data-rcb-resource-mimetype^=image]").each(function (i,node) {
```

With

```
$("section[data-role='conents']").find("span[data-rcb-resource-mimetype^=image]").each(function (i,node) {
```

Comment: Hey thanks Prasanth but unfortunately this did not worked for me.actually what I was trying to do si pass the html block from use of a parameter . and call it on the onload of the body

Comment: for doing that you can use `<script>$(function(){ // code here is executed on body load });</script>`